# Laravel visitors counter

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm trying to build a visitors counter in Laravel....

I don't know what the best place is to put the code inside so that it loads on EVERY page... But I putted it inside of the routes.php....

I think I'll better place it inside of basecontroller?

But okay, My code looks like this now:

```
    //stats

$date = new \DateTime;

$check_if_exists = DB::table('visitor')->where('ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])->first();

$get_visit_day = DB::table('visitor')->select('visit_date')->where('ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])->first();

$value = date_create($get_visit_day->visit_date);

if(!$check_if_exists)
{

    DB::table('visitor')->insert(array('ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 'hits' => '1', 'visit_date' => $date));

}else{

    DB::table('visitor')->where('ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])->increment('hits');
}


$value = date_create($get_visit_day->visit_date);

if ($check_if_exists && date_format($value, 'd') != date('d')) {

    DB::table('visitor')->insert(array('ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 'hits' => '1', 'visit_date' => $date));
}
```

That works fine, but the problem is, my database columns always add a new value.

So this is my database:
[image: With the table 'visitor']

From the table 'visitor'.

It keeps adding a new IP, hit and visit_date...

How is it possible to just update the hits from today (the day) and if the day is passed, to set a new IP value and count in that column?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but you should be able to do something like this. It's not tested, and there may be a more elegant way to do it, but it's a starting point for you.

**Change the table**

Change the `visit_date (datetime)` column into `visit_date (date)` and `visit_time (time)` columns, then create an `id` column to be the primary key. Lastly, set `ip + date` to be a unique key to ensure you can't have the same IP entered twice for one day.

**Create an Eloquent model**

This is just for ease: make an Eloquent model for the table so you don't have to use Fluent (query builder) all the time:

```
class Tracker extends Eloquent {

    public $attributes = [ 'hits' => 0 ];

    protected $fillable = [ 'ip', 'date' ];
    protected $table = 'table_name';

    public static function boot() {
        // Any time the instance is updated (but not created)
        static::saving( function ($tracker) {
            $tracker->visit_time = date('H:i:s');
            $tracker->hits++;
        } );
    }

    public static function hit() {
        static::firstOrCreate([
                  'ip'   => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                  'date' => date('Y-m-d'),
              ])->save();
    }

}
```

Now you should be able to do what you want by just calling this:

```
Tracker::hit();
```

Comment: Maybe just use a unique compound key. The primary key could still simply be a standard auto incrementing ID, which would likely perform better.

Comment: @Seer yeah, that probably works better, looking back on it. Originally I was thinking you could use that to make `firstOrCreate` limit itself to the day/ip combination, but since that's being specified in Eloquent anyway, that's redundant

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::firstOrCreate() is the error I'm getting...

Comment: @Advil I suspect I may have botched the setup for `firstOrCreate` - check the updated post as that may work now. Docs are at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete if you need

Comment: @Joe Now the error has changed to just the message 'ip' screen can be found here: http://prntscr.com/6usgqs

Comment: @Advil fixed that; it just needs to be marked as 'fillable'. That said, Martin's answer below looks much more elegant than mine and is probably worth checking out

Comment: @Joe Your version does not add multiple times the same IP adress, If I change the day, then it does update the date back to today and keeps counting...

Answer (score 5):

Looking at your code and reading your description, I’m assuming you want to calculate number of hits from an IP address per day. You could do this using Eloquent’s `updateOrNew()` method:

```
$ip = Request::getClientIp();
$visit_date = Carbon::now()->toDateString();

$visitor = Visitor::findOrNew(compact('ip', 'visit_date'));
$visitor->increment('hits');
```

However, I would add this to a queue so you’re not hitting the database on every request and incrementing your hit count can be done via a background process:

```
Queue::push('RecordVisit', compact('ip', 'visit_date'));
```

In terms of where to bootstrap this, the `App::before()` filter sounds like a good candidate:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    $ip = $request->getClientIp();
    $visit_date = Carbon::now()->toDateString();

    Queue::push('RecordVisit', compact('ip', 'visit_date'));
);
```

You could go one step further by listening for this event in a service provider and firing your queue job there, so that your visit counter is its own self-contained component and can be added or removed easily from this and any other projects.

Comment: @Advil Where ever you want to log a visit. I’d suggest the `App::before()` filter.

Comment: When I put everything inside `app::before() `, it gives me this error: http://prntscr.com/6utyyk The `App::before()` looks like this: http://prntscr.com/6utzmf

Comment: @Advil Sorry, the method’s called `getClientIp()`, or you can use the shorter `ip()` method. I’ve updated my answer.

Comment: It doesn't work... I placed everything inside of the `App::before()`, but still, I created a model calles `Visitor`, but it doesn't work.... the error I'm getting: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::updateOrNew()

Comment: @Advil Sorry, my bad again. Try `findOrNew()` instead. I wrote the code off the cuff.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Joe for helping me fulley out!

@Martin, you also thanks, but the scripts of @Joe worked for my problem.

The solution:

```
Tracker::hit();
```

Inside my App::before();

And a new class:

```
<?php

class Tracker Extends Eloquent {

    public $attributes = ['hits' => 0];

    protected $fillable = ['ip', 'date'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'visitor';

    public static function boot() {
        // When a new instance of this model is created...
        static::creating(function ($tracker) {
            $tracker->hits = 0;
        } );

        // Any time the instance is saved (create OR update)
        static::saving(function ($tracker) {
            $tracker->visit_date = date('Y-m-d');
            $tracker->visit_time = date('H:i:s');
            $tracker->hits++;
        } );
    }

    // Fill in the IP and today's date
    public function scopeCurrent($query) {
        return $query->where('ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
                     ->where('date', date('Y-m-d'));
    }

    public static function hit() {
        static::firstOrCreate([
                  'ip'   => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                  'date' => date('Y-m-d'),
              ])->save();
    }
}
```

Named 'tracker' :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public $attributes = ['hits' => 0];

protected $fillable = ['ip', 'date'];

public $timestamps = false;

protected $table = 'trackers';

public static function boot() {
    // When a new instance of this model is created...
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function ($tracker) {
        $tracker->hits = 0;
    } );

    // Any time the instance is saved (create OR update)
    static::saving(function ($tracker) {
        $tracker->visit_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $tracker->visit_time = date('H:i:s');
        $tracker->hits++;
    } );
}

// Fill in the IP and today's date
public function scopeCurrent($query) {
    return $query->where('ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
                 ->where('date', date('Y-m-d'));
}

public static function hit() {
   /* $test= request()->server('REMOTE_ADDR');
    echo $test;
    exit();*/
    static::firstOrCreate([
              'ip'   => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],

              'date' => date('Y-m-d'),
             // exit()
          ])->save();

}
```

In laravel 5.7 it required parent::boot() otherwise it will show Undefined index: App\Tracker
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25455

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did its very basic but can easily build it up and add filters on visitors per day month year etc..

i added the following code to the web.php file above all the routes to run on each request on the site so no matter what page the visitor landed on it will save the ip addess to the database only if its unique so one visitor wont keep addding to the visitor count

```
// Web.php
use App\Models\Visitor

$unique_ip = true;
$visitors = Visitor::all();
foreach($visitors as $visitor){
    if($visitor->ip_address == request()->ip()){
        $unique_ip = false;
    }
}
if($unique_ip == true){
    $visitor = Visitor::create([
        'ip_address' => request()->ip(),
    ]);
}

Routes...
```

the model is straight forward just has a ip addess field