# How to count visitors of my website in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am new to Laravel 5.

I want to count the number of visitor of my website. I already followed this steps in [laravel visitors counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694372/laravel-visitors-counter) but it did not work.

Is there any other solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Just use this library it provides lot of option for Tracking

> https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker

Just install the dependency

```
composer require pragmarx/tracker
```

Add the service provider to your app/config/app.php:

```
'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider',
```

Add the alias to the facade on your app/config/app.php:

```
'Tracker' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Facade',
```

Comment: This one doesn't work. I tried installing it, so much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```html
public function post(post $post)
 {   
  $key = 'myblog'.$post->id; 
  if (!Session::has($key)) {
        $post->increment('view_count');
        Session::put($key , 1);
  }

 
   return view('frontend.post.show',compact('post'));
 }
```