# how get views number for my website in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

my code : but always views number are 1

```
public function getLandPage()
    {

        if(is_null(Session::get('views_number'))){
            Session::put('views_number',1);
        }else{
            $c=Session::get('views_number');
            $c++;
            Session::put('views_number',$c);
        }

        return dd( Session::get('views_number'));
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29694985/7398574  may be this might help you

Comment: Whats the version of your laravel?

Comment: my version is 5.1

Comment: Laravel 5.1 have changed the sessions structure. Please look at my command http://stackoverflow.com/a/42531495/4049692

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DemoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {

         ( $request->session()->has('views_number') ) ? $request->session()->put('views_number',  (session('views_number') + 1) ) : $request->session()->put('views_number',   1) ;
          echo session('views_number');
    }
}
```

Comment: useful code but not share for all users , this work for one user

Comment: Do you want to show the total number of page viewed from anywhere?

Comment: If you use session it will only access browser leavel. My suggestion is create common page_views table. Based on Post ID make an insert in table. If post is exist make an update. Session and Cookie is not a best for this. This is my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a total number of views (not per user) use the Cache:

```
Cache::increment('views_number');
return dd(Cache::get('views_number'));
```